# Remove password from excel

Tags: excel, forgot-password, locked

Before writing my question, I made a search throughout your database and unfortunately could not find any answer to the question, which seems to have been asked by several other people.

Today I am experiencing this issue, whereby an excel document is locked for editing by a password, which I have forgotten.

Was any fix found for this issue?

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards.

[Please see illustration of the message received when trying to edit the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQrDT.png)

Comment: Is it xls or xlsx?

Comment: It is in .xlsx alex

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-or-remove-workbook-passwords-1c17af87-25e2-4dc6-94f0-19ce21ad0b68

i hope it works for you

Comment: @Vish missed the password so you link is not useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help article but it is for the Mac 2011, and I am on Windows.  I know, through some articles that excel in Mac and Windows differ by quite a variety of features.

Comment: I forgot the password correct Nicolaesse.
This morning, while discussing this issue with some colleagues, one of them came and put a password that was being used at the time I protected the sheet.  It did the job, the excel file has now been unprotected and luckily the password I set was related to my job itself.
Thank you all for the help, very much appreciated.
Have a lovely day, cheers.